# How to fetch copied content from a clipboard - Selenium headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a webpage with a "Copy Link" button, clicking on it copies some data from the text box.  Also, these selenium tests will run on Linux machines (headless mode). I used awt Toolkit api and it failed with below stack trace because its running in Linux headless mode. Toolkit doesn't seen to be supported in Linux mode

```
Test Failed: {}[class: tests.AMUSanityTests, method: test, exception: java.awt.HeadlessException, message: 'No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.', stack trace: 
sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getSystemClipboard(HeadlessToolkit.java:309)
```

I also tried using selenium sendKeys but this is a void method and hence i cannot fetch the content. There is no place on the webpage for me to paste the content and again copy it for verification.

I need a way to extract the copied content for verification purposes.

Does someone have a solution on how this can be achieved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small class that does it in a way:

```
public class ClipboardUtil {

    public static String fetchClipboardContents() throws IOException {
        String contents = "";
        String command = "xclip --clipboard -o";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            contents = br.readLine();
        }
        return contents;
    }

}
```

The static method executes a linux command `xclip --clipboard -o`, which outputs the clipboard's contents to the terminal. Java takes the output and returns it as a string.

You could execute some other command in linux that would get you the desired output and the java code should remain the same.

INFO:

I used Ubuntu to write this code. The example command returns the copied content or the currently selected content. Using a different linux command is a good idea.

Comment: Running this linux command throws following error on the terminal Error: Can't open display: (null)

Comment: One could find a different command that gets the job done, or write a custom shell script if everything else fails. If you could output your clipboard contents to the terminal, you could get the same info in java.

Comment: @IvanDimitrov Are you sure this works in _headless_ mode?

Comment: @RedYeti Check this answer out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/305654/xclip-on-headless-server

This explains the xclip stuff on headless servers. xclip is a utility that works as a terminal clipboard, which this java code runs.

You need an x server running anyway.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @IvanDimitrov Thanks! Not sure if that works without having an X-server though.